# how to configure variable for read_in txt file like '0x12c'

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my c1.txt file, i have something like

```
var0 = '0x000000000000004080'
```

And in my python mail file:

```
def getVarFromFile(filename):
  import imp
  f = open(filename)
  global data
  data = imp.load_source('data', '', f)
  f.close()
getVarFromFile('c1.txt')
```

The var0 is a 72-bit variable, and in my python file, I want to assign that to 12 variable with 6-bit for each, how can I do that?

Since var0 is a hex variable, seems I can't do

```
x = int(data.var1) & 0x3F
```

Thanks

Comment: x = int(data.var1, **16**) & 0x3F may works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do in your last line is provide a base for the integer conversion:

```
values_from_hex = int(data.var1, 16)
```

Then you can divide the value up into your 6-bit values (least significant bits first):

```
six_bit_values = [values_from_hex >> i*6 & 0x3f for i in range(12)]
```

For a value of `'0x000000000000004080'`, this gets `[0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

Comment: `int(data.var1, 0)` also works, and will continue work if the user switch to decimal.